# change attribute's value in directive angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I building a directive for image tags when src attribute's value is empty then change src value with default value .

```
.directive('defaultImage', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    compile : function compile(tElement, tAttributes) {

        return {
            pre : function preLink(scope, element, attributes) {
            },
            post : function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                if (attrs.src == undefined || attrs.src.length == 0) {
                    element.attr('src', '/delegate/resource/admin/images/default.png');
                    $compile(element)(scope);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
});
```

usage :

```
<img src="{{entity.image}}" style="margin-left: 20px"
     height="120px" width="140px" default-image>
```

but this not work.

Comment: Tested. Code works fine. Show how you use it maybe.

Comment: Hi, in my opinion, the logic you wrote in the directive should be done in the place where you retrieve the image source.

Answer (score 1):

First, are you familiar with `ng-src`? It's used for interpolated src expressions to avoid the browser trying to fetch from `"path/to/{{url}}"` instead of the actual url (e.g. `"/path/to/image1.png"`). It also doesn't load the image if `url` is `undefined`.

Second, the `$compile(element)(scope)` is completely unnecessary (and in fact, incorrect) - if nothing else, you are needlessly recompiling the `defaultImage` directive.

**EDIT:**

Huh... this is a case of "overthinking" on my part... By far, the easiest way to achieve a default URL is like so (no directives required):

```
<img ng-src="{{entity.image || '/default/url'}}">
```

Or, if you have a scope variable `$scope.defaultUrl`, then:

```
<img ng-src="{{entity.image || defaultUrl}}">
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

So, let's see how `ngSrc` handles the "good" case and create something similar for the default case. Here's a simplified snippet of code from the [`ngSrc` source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.5/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L412):

```
link: function(scope, element, attr){

  attr.$observe("ngSrc", function(value) {
    if (!value) {
      return;
    }

    attr.$set("src", value);

    // on IE, if "ng:src" directive declaration is used and "src" attribute doesn't exist
    // then calling element.setAttribute('src', 'foo') doesn't do anything, so we need
    // to set the property as well to achieve the desired effect.
    // we use attr[attrName] value since $set can sanitize the url.
    if (msie) element.prop("src", attr["src"]);
  });
}
```

So, using a similar approach:

```
.directive("defaultImage", function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr){

      // what Angular uses 
      // https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.5/src/Angular.js#L191
      var msie = document.documentMode;

      var defaultImageUrl = "/path/to/default.png";

      attr.$observe("ngSrc", function(value){
         if (!value){
           attr.$set("src", defaultImageUrl);
           if (msie) element.prop("src", attr["src"]);
         }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mR6z7apdgqoVSnaaC9I0?p=preview)**